# Command not found: pipenv

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

```bsh
~/twint$ pipenv install -e git+https://github.com/twintproject/twint.git#egg=twint
pipenv: command not found
```

I have pip and python installed.

Comment: Can you please try installing `pipenv` first using `pip install pipenv`?

Comment: DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Requirement already satisfied: pipenv in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (2018.11.26)

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: enum34; python_version < "3" in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pipenv) (1.1.6)

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pipenv) (0.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=9.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pipenv) (19.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36.2.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pipenv) (39.0.1)

Comment: I'd guess that pipenv isn't in your PATH. Check out the installation section in the pipenv documentation.

Comment: can i have the link please

Answer (score 4):

In Python3, you can install it with:

```
$~ pip3 install pipenv
```

Comment: Doesn't work :( - "No matching distribution found for pipenv"

Answer (score 0):

It seems `pipenv` can be installed directly from the apt repositories. Try running `sudo apt install pipenv`.

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pipenv

Comment: @JulianWilliams It's only available on the (non-LTS) 19 version http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/man1/pipenv.1.html